# mingw : Giving reference to opencv libraries in simpler way

Tags: opencv, mingw

Successfully installed opencv 4.5.4 in windows under mingw evironment. I was able to compile opencv applications. But is there any easy way to give reference to libraries instead of typing long list of opencv libraries (i.e. something like pkg-config in windows)

For a simple opencv program I need to give reference to 4 libraries.

g++ rotate.cpp   -lopencv_core454 -lopencv_highgui454 -lopencv_imgproc454 -lopencv_imgcodecs454
instead do we have some option to give list of libraries through some flags in windows environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `pkg-config` in Windows. If you use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell is is usually available or it can be installed via `pacman`.